# Finding trends in multi-category data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, statistics

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains hundreds of rows of data that each represent a single sample in a larger population.  Each row is divided into three columns that contain frequency counts of a specific type of thing.  Together the three columns summed on a single row represent 100%, though each row will sum to a different value.

What I'm most interested in are the proportions of each of these types (ie. percentages of each column relative to the sum of the three columns).  I can easily calculate this on a per-row basis, but what I'm really interested in is trying to find an overall trend from the entire population.

I don't really spend much time doing data analysis so the only thing I can think of trying is to create those percentage columns and then average them, but I'm sure there must be a better way to visualise this.

Answer (score 0):

I would "UnPivot" the data so that each row produces three rows, with an added Type column.  In this format you can sum the counts by Type over the whole population e.g. with a Pivot Table.

The best "UnPivot" tool is the Power Query Add-In for Excel:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/unpivot-columns-HA104053356.aspx

Comment: I'm not really used to using pivot tables, but I don't think what you're describing is what I'm after.  I'm not really interested in the sum of each column, I'm interested in its proportion to the other columns.  ie. if row 1 has A/B/C of 100/10/50, that's exactly as significant as row 2 having 10000/1000/5000, and different from row 3 having 50/10/100.  I'm interested in the "small" samples too, and I don't want the "large" samples to dominate them.

Comment: You can do that using a Pivot Table - you add the Row number/identifier to the row labels and Type to the column labels, then change the Value to show as % of Row Total.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is a data exploration problem, not an Excel or charting problem (although they can both help solve your problem).  Without seeing your data (even a small sample would be helpful), here's a methodology that may help.

1. Convert your data into an Excel Table.
2. Add a percentage column for each data column, then calculate it's percentage of the whole (e.g. in your sample, `=A2/sum(A2:C2)`
3. Sort your Table by the percentage column for your values. Using a custom sort, you can have it sort by multiple criteria.  One approach is to sort using your columns in their order of importance (e.g. assuming Column A is most important, sort by it first, followed by Column B, second most important...).
4. Create a stacked bar chart from your table data and you can begin looking for patterns.

Here's a sample of what it could look like.  If you can provide some data, and some more detail, we can make this more suited to your needs.

[image: DataExplore]